# Why does Gridview.PagerSettings.PreviousPageText or NextPageText ignore "blank spaces"

Tags: c#, gridview

I am trying to customize the verbiage at the top of Gridview for paging by manipulating the 
PagerSettings text fields, and while this is working great ... I have the following code, but no matter how I try to trick the control, I still get the same result

[prev][next][last]

I want

[prev]     [next]     [last]

here is the code:

```
sb.Clear();
                    sb.Append("[next]".PadRight(10));
                    sb.Append("[prev]".PadRight(10));
                    sb.Append("[last]");

                    ReportGV.PagerSettings.PreviousPageText = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Have you tried changing it on the aspx page directly? add `<PagerSettings Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" FirstPageText="First " LastPageText="Last " NextPageText="Next " PreviousPageText="Prev " PageButtonCount="5" Position="Bottom" />`